# Laptop going to sleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep, overheating, diagnostic

I have Dell Precision 5510 with Windows 10 and I am encountering issued when playing Fallout 4.

When I play the laptop is going to sleep after some time. How can I diagnose what is happening? Can it be caused by overheating or something similar?

Comment: Overheating will not cause sleep. It will cause a shutdown.

Comment: Then how to diagnose why it going to sleep when playing game?

Comment: Look in the system event log for `Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power` events.

Comment: Sleep Reason: Application API

Comment: What else? There must be other information with the event.